# why text is not render in reactjs using enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, enzyme

could you please tell me why the test case not running in react using enzyme?

I install enzyme js and follow this tutorial 
https://javascriptplayground.com/introduction-to-react-tests-enzyme/

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import Hello from './Hello';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('renders', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Hello name="Jack" />);
  expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toEqual('Hello, Jack!');
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x6oqkyknn

Comment: Just make it `spec` with a small s

Comment: not working ..could you please look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing with test not being found was an issue with naming.

codesandbox is using character sensitive regex and you have to make it `Hello.spec.js` for it to be detected.

Here is the sandbox forked from your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/649owm14o3

Also, to have the test actually work you have to setup a `enzyme-adapter-react-16` and have it setup like:

```
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Typically you would do this in a different file, but for the purposes of this demo, I have set it up in the same file.

Also note the typo comma "Hello Jack"